# Finding variance

Tags: c#, calculator, variance

I'm trying to Add a static method to calculate the average of a, array of integers, Overload the method in a. to also calculate an array of doubles. 
Add a method to calculate the sum of an array of integers or doubles 
Add a method to calculate the variance in an array of integers or doubles. 
Add a method to calculate the standard deviation of an array of integers or doubles.

I've finished most of the code but ran into a problem when I created the method to calculate the variance.

I've tried different things in here but it always gives me an error, I believe that the Math.Pow is what is messing this up.  Is there another way and possibly simpler way to compute the variance with the rest of the code?

```
class States
{
    private static int Sum(int[] a)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += a[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static double Average(int[] a)
    {
        int sum = Sum(a);
        double Avg = (double)sum / a.Length;
        return Avg;
    }

//this is where i am having trouble

    private static double Var(int[] a)

    {

        if (a.Length > 1)

        {

            double Avg = Average(a);

            double var = 0.0;



            foreach (int A in Average)

            {

                // Math.Pow to calculate variance? 

                var += Math.Pow((A - Average)), 2.0) 

            }

            return var;

        }

        else

        {

            return 0.0;

        }
        private static double StdDev(double var)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(var);
        }
    }
}
```

> "Foreach cannot operate on a method group"

Comment: You don't have a variable named `Average`...

Comment: `foreach (int A in Average)` should be `foreach (int A in a)` I suspect. _`Average` is the name of a function (a `method group`). You didn't invoke it (no `(` or `)`). Now, keeping that in mind - read the error message again._

Comment: Most of your issues would be solved if you renamed your `Average` function to `CalculateAverage` (same for `CalculateVariance`) - so you aren't making the mistake where you are confusing `Avg` for `Average` etc etc. Also, the first character in local variables should be lower case (i.e. `a` rather than `A`). Also, I would strongly suggest not naming variables `var` since that has another meaning in C#.

Comment: Note that you can double-click compile errors in the error list (assuming you're using Visual Studio) and it will take you to the line causing the problem (in most cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class States
{
    private static int Sum(int[] values)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += values[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static double Average(int[] values)
    {
        int sum = Sum(values);
        double avg = (double)sum / values.Length;
        return avg;
    }

    //this is where i am having trouble
    public static double Variance(int[] values)
    {
        if (values.Length > 1)
        {
            double avg = Average(values);
            double variance = 0.0;
            foreach (int value in values)
            {
                // Math.Pow to calculate variance? 
                variance += Math.Pow(value - avg, 2.0);
            }
            return variance / values.Length; // For sample variance
        }
        else
        {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }

    private static double StdDev(double var)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(var);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers